# Radio Button doesn't work inside my GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, radio-button

I have a GridView. Every row has a **textbox** and a **radiobutton** (3 options)

If the radiobutton is selected then the `textbox.text = ""`

Problem: when `OnSelectedIndexChanged` is called every textbox inside my grid goes blank

How can I clear only the textbox of the row I selected the radiobutton in?

**ASPX markup**

```
<asp:GridView id="mygrid" Runat="server">
   <Columns>            
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:RadioButtonList ID="hi" runat="server" 
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="zzz" AutoPostBack="true" />
               <asp:TextBox ID="txPregoeiro" runat="server" Text="." />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**C# code-behind**

```
protected void zzz(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow _row in mygrid.Rows)
    {
        if (_row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            RadioButtonList hi = (RadioButtonList)_row.FindControl("hi");
            TextBox txPregoeiro = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("txPregoeiro");
            txPregoeiro.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code and what you tried

Comment: Thanks for the interest...Take a look

Comment: thanks marc_s it's not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently doing it for every row which will clear every text box. Give this a try.

```
 protected void zzz(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var caller = (RadionButtonList)sender;

        foreach (GridViewRow _row in mygrid.Rows)
        {
            if (_row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                RadioButtonList hi = (RadioButtonList)_row.FindControl("hi");

                if(hi == caller) 
                {
                  TextBox txPregoeiro = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("txPregoeiro");
                  txPregoeiro.Text = string.Empty;
                  break; //a match was found break from the loop
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull

Comment: No problem. There is a slight issue with the answer you chose though that you should be aware of. Doing it that way you are sending out one event no matter which control was clicked and updating every textbox in the grid no matter which radio button list was selected. This would be the same as just having a single button at the top that looped through the grid and checked to see which ones were selected then cleared the text boxes. Getting the caller will only affect the row you are on (the only one you care about at the time of making the selection). Note: added a break.

Comment: Good catch @StephenBrickner. I updated my answer so it gets the selected row first and then clears out the textbox. This was you don't do any looping at all to find the selected row.

Comment: @John Paul, SelectedRow effectively does the same enumeration but that is much more concise, good work. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your not checking to see if the radio button list has a selected item or not. As a result you are always setting the textbox text to blank. Change the function to:

```
    GridViewRow _row = mygrid.SelectedRow;
    if (_row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButtonList hi = (RadioButtonList)_row.FindControl("hi");
        if(hi.SelectedItem != null) //This checks to see if a radio button in the list was selected
        {
            TextBox txPregoeiro = (TextBox)_row.FindControl("txPregoeiro");
            txPregoeiro.Text = string.Empty;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpfull